Movie where two small kids see an alien; then see them again as adults
I remember a movie from somewhere in the late 70's to early 80's where there were two kids that saw an alien or possibly just a space ship. They meet again as adults in the same place and see them again. I don't remember much more than that. The kids were one boy and one girl. I don't even remember if it was any good but then again I was likely just coming up on being a teenager and a geeky one at that. So I think I was intrigued. 
Any ideas or do I need to plumb my memory for more details as that's all I have at the moment?


The Return (1980)
Based on your description, and the timeline, this should be the movie. A brief synopsis:


A UFO hovers over a small New Mexico town, enveloping two children in
  a cone of translucent mist.



25 years later, Jennifer Kramer, has grown up and become an
  astrophysicist. She returns to the town to investigate strange
  satellite readings coming from the area that leave an intense fogging
  on photos.



Jennifer meets up with town deputy Wayne Thompson and realizes that he
  is the other child from 25 years ago...

~ Edited from MORIA
Read reviews here and here. Watch a murky YouTube clip or go on over to VEEHD for the full movie.

It's Stringfellow Hawk!

:-) Always had a soft spot for that show. Cheesy? Sure. But loved that intro!
